# Object invalid given context EJB migration

Tags: binding, ejb-3.0

A bit of background as to what I am trying to do, I am migrating to EJB3.0 and I want to do as little as possible to make this work - no annotations etc. So I created the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file, which looks like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1">

<session simple-binding-name="ejb/test/TEST" name="TEST"> 
<ejb-ref name="ejb/TEST" binding-name="ejb/test/TEST"/> 
<resource-ref name="jdbc/THISNAME" binding-name="jdbc/THIS"/> </session> 
<session simple-binding-name="ejb/test/NEWTEST" name="NEWTEST"> 
<ejb-ref name="ejb/NEWTEST" binding-name="ejb/test/NEWTEST"/> 
<resource-ref name="jdbc/THISNAME" binding-name="jdbc/THIS"/> </session>


</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

after the update from the .xmi file I am receiving the following error not that ejb/Test is a remote ejb, in the .xmi file it was referred to with,

```
<ejbRefBindings xmi:id="EjbRefBinding_1111111111111" jndiName="ejb/test/TEST">
```

Error:-

Some object reference in the name "ejb/test/TEST" relative to the context "HOST" is invalid.  Some possible causes include a context binding in the name which refers to a destroyed context, or an object binding which contains an invalid EJBHome reference.

Comment: adding more information - can you use Home interfaces with ejb3.0 or are they made obsolete?